How to troubleshoot postfix repeatedly sending same email
EDIT:

Added output of postconf -n and postconf -M as suggested
AA425A04D2 was sent and removed from the queue

Since Friday afternoon (July 19) at about 5:30pm, my email server has been repeatedly sending the same email - about every 30 seconds. Nothing was updated or upgraded, no configuration files were changed. Restarting the process (and the entire box the process sits on) does not fix the issue. This email was originally sent out and received July 12th without any trouble or repeat from an email client running on my personal computer.
This does not seem to be a queue issue; I've cleared the queue and looked through every directory in the postfix spool. I'm not sure where else to look.
Some process on the server seems to be resubmitting this email - it appears briefly in the queue and then sends. I've disconnected every email client that I have and restarted the postfix process, to no effect. It seems to be a local process [127.0.0.1] that resubmits the email.
How do I track down where this email is and what is sending it?
Here is what repeats in the mail log (from this morning - this repeats over and over. The postfix/cleanup keeps referencing the same message-id <6063969.lOV4Wx5bFT@nuguk-x1b> (nuguk-x1b is my laptop):
Jul 21 11:50:09 loki postfix/smtpd[19418]: connect from loki.localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jul 21 11:50:09 loki postfix/smtpd[19418]: 07736A04A1: client=loki.localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jul 21 11:50:09 loki postfix/cleanup[19420]: 07736A04A1: message-id=<6063969.lOV4Wx5bFT@nuguk-x1b>
Jul 21 11:50:30 loki opendkim[982]: 07736A04A1: DKIM-Signature field added (s=smtp, d=sender.com)
Jul 21 11:50:30 loki postfix/qmgr[19107]: 07736A04A1: from=<sender@domain.com>, size=31595658, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
Jul 21 11:50:30 loki postfix/smtpd[19418]: disconnect from loki.localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jul 21 11:50:34 loki postfix/smtpd[19418]: connect from loki.localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jul 21 11:50:34 loki postfix/smtpd[19418]: AA425A04D2: client=loki.localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jul 21 11:50:35 loki postfix/cleanup[19420]: AA425A04D2: message-id=<6063969.lOV4Wx5bFT@nuguk-x1b>
Jul 21 11:50:36 loki postfix/smtp[19430]: 07736A04A1: to=<recipient1@recipient1.com>, relay=recipient1-com01i.mail.protection.outlook.com[52.101.41.4]:25, delay=27, delays=22/0.01/0.22/5.5, dsn=2.6.0, status=sent (250 2.6.0 <6063969.lOV4Wx5bFT@nuguk-x1b> [InternalId=57578331578589, Hostname=PH7PR13MB6268.namprd13.prod.outlook.com] 31607288 bytes in 4.514, 6836.615 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery)
Jul 21 11:50:41 loki postfix/smtp[19431]: 07736A04A1: to=<recipient2@recipient2.com>, relay=outlook-com.olc.protection.outlook.com[52.101.68.28]:25, delay=33, delays=22/0.02/0.93/10, dsn=2.6.0, status=sent (250 2.6.0 <6063969.lOV4Wx5bFT@nuguk-x1b> [InternalId=1142461310207, Hostname=CPTP152MB4086.LAMP152.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM] 31605459 bytes in 7.875, 3918.924 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery -> 250 2.1.5)
Jul 21 11:50:41 loki postfix/qmgr[19107]: 07736A04A1: removed

output of postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
local_recipient_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap/local_recipient_maps.cf
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 41943040
milter_default_action = accept
mydestination = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap/mydestination.cf
mydomain = sender.com
myhostname = smtp.sender.com
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
recipient_delimiter = +
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
smtpd_data_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, check_policy_service unix:private/recipient_policy_incoming
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service unix:private/recipient_policy_incoming, permit
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sender_login_maps = $local_recipient_maps
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_sender_login_mismatch, check_policy_service unix:private/sender_policy_incoming
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/smtp.sender.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/smtp.sender.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
submission_data_restrictions = check_policy_service unix:private/submission_policy
submission_recipient_restrictions = check_policy_service unix:private/submission_policy, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
submission_sender_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_sender, check_policy_service unix:private/submission_policy, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
transport_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap/transport_maps.cf, hash:/etc/postfix/transport
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = $alias_maps, ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap/virtual_alias_maps.cf, ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap/virtual_alias_maps_mailforwarding.cf, ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap/virtual_alias_maps_sharedfolders.cf, ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap/mailenabled_distgroups.cf, ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap/mailenabled_dynamic_distgroups.cf

output of postconf -M
smtp       inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
submission inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -o cleanup_service_name=cleanup_submission -o syslog_name=postfix/submission -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o smtpd_data_restrictions=$submission_data_restrictions -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=$submission_recipient_restrictions -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$submission_sender_restrictions
pickup     fifo  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup -o header_checks=regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks.inbound -o mime_header_checks=regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks.inbound
cleanup_internal unix n  -       n       -       0       cleanup -o header_checks=regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks.internal -o mime_header_checks=regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks.internal
cleanup_submission unix n -      n       -       0       cleanup -o header_checks=regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks.submission -o mime_header_checks=regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks.submission
qmgr       fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
showq      unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
smtp-amavis unix -       -       n       -       3       smtp -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1800 -o disable_dns_lookups=yes -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes -o max_use=20 -o smtp_bind_address=127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1:10025 inet n   -       n       -       100     smtpd -o cleanup_service_name=cleanup_internal -o content_filter=smtp-wallace:[127.0.0.1]:10026 -o local_recipient_maps= -o relay_recipient_maps= -o smtpd_restriction_classes= -o smtpd_client_restrictions= -o smtpd_helo_restrictions= -o smtpd_sender_restrictions= -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8 -o smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts=127.0.0.0/8
smtp-wallace unix -      -       n       -       3       smtp -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1800 -o disable_dns_lookups=yes -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes -o max_use=20
127.0.0.1:10027 inet n   -       n       -       100     smtpd -o cleanup_service_name=cleanup_internal -o content_filter= -o local_recipient_maps= -o relay_recipient_maps= -o smtpd_restriction_classes= -o smtpd_client_restrictions= -o smtpd_helo_restrictions= -o smtpd_sender_restrictions= -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8 -o smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts=127.0.0.0/8
recipient_policy unix -  n       n       -       -       spawn user=kolab-n argv=/usr/libexec/postfix/kolab_smtp_access_policy --verify-recipient
recipient_policy_incoming unix - n n     -       -       spawn user=kolab-n argv=/usr/libexec/postfix/kolab_smtp_access_policy --verify-recipient --allow-unauthenticated
sender_policy unix -     n       n       -       -       spawn user=kolab-n argv=/usr/libexec/postfix/kolab_smtp_access_policy --verify-sender
sender_policy_incoming unix - n  n       -       -       spawn user=kolab-n argv=/usr/libexec/postfix/kolab_smtp_access_policy --verify-sender --allow-unauthenticated
submission_policy unix - n       n       -       -       spawn user=kolab-n argv=/usr/libexec/postfix/kolab_smtp_access_policy --verify-sender --verify-recipient


First of all, 127.0.0.1 shouldn't be reverse-resolved as anything other than just localhost; something is wrong with your DNS setup. Next, I see submission of the same messsage twice, as 07736A04A1 and AA425A04D2. Do you have any after-queue mail processing? (Also, it seems to enter via standard port 25, which is not good; mail should be submitted via dedicated submission or smtps service instead.) Please, append your Postfix configs as suggested in the tag description, and if there is external processing, describe it too.

In my experience, the repeated delivery of the message may happen if there are several recipients (address expansion in effect) and some of expanded recipients show temporary error (any 4xx, for example, insufficient mailbox space and so on); then postfix attempts delivery again periodically, but it expands it again, so  other recipients may receive the same message more than once. But here it doesn't look like the case. What happened to AA425A04D2 after it has been queued?
